# Uses of enslaved dragons

Tags: dragons, slavery

People of my had come to continent about 4000 years ago, only other races that could not be considered animals and have some significant quantity were dragons and goblins. As those new folks were quite warlike and warable, they'd conquered all of them and promptly enslaved indigenous species. When goblins are perfect creatures to become slaves (not so intelligent, physically inferior and to divided to put some resistance), dragons are another story.
Dragons are big, have heavy armor of scales, breath liquid fire, hoard gold, intelligent, spiteful and proud. There was no hope in enslaving them nicely, only heavy chains, cut wings and special drugs could hold them in place with little chance of burning everything around. This mean they're no use as beast of burden, war mount, living attack aircraft and so on.

So, there's my question, **how to use those those dragons the best in given circumstances?**

Ideas I had, is to use them as heat sources for furnaces or steam locomotives.

Setting we have is your typical fantasy world with technology from XVII/XVIII century.

Comment: It's very easy to think of stuff. Dragon milk, dragon blood, dragon scales, dragon meat, dragon bone - all sorts of animal products that might be used. It takes me less time to come up with ideas than writing them down which tells me that you need to be more specific of what you want. Furnaces are well, stiff to burn isn't really as expensive and much more reliable than housing and feeding a dragon. Are you going for pure fantasy? Is it more important to you to do something 'awsome' than something rational? That's the star wars mindset, it's fine - but a different question

Comment: You don't want dragon dead, it's really hard to come by with new one. Temperature of dragon breath is much higher then from any other source, so that's why you use them.

Comment: Also, more "awesome" part of usage spectrum would be better.

Comment: maybe using their dung as fertilizer ? guano is pretty valuable at that time, since getting dragon pretty much help industrialization, and having massive dung can increase farm yield production.

Comment: Hmm, that would be interesting, great crop fields around train tracks, where they dispose dragon dung. I guess it would add some spiciness to food.

Comment: Siege weapons / artillery, a chained dragon could be pointed at the enemy gate, or army. It's usefulness would depend on the reach of it's breath. If sieges are still a thing, the wings could be crippled without being cut off, protecting the soldiers from projectiles coming from above as they push it towards the gate.

Comment: Milking them for pyrophoric/hypergolic flame fuel could be notable. You might even have a pretty substantial dragon-based chemical engineering base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your current dragons are not the same as the dragons of 4000 years ago.**

Wolves are big, fast, wary, intelligent, eat children and carry rabies.  Now their descendants sleep in our beds with us.

If you took control of the dragons 4000 years ago, the fact that there are still dragons means you allowed some to reproduce.  You chose some of them to reproduce for some reason; certainly you could not have dragons just wandering around, reproducing and eating children ad libitum.

You chose dragons to reproduce based on some quality.  Probably small size since if you had them captive you needed to feed them which is expensive.  Probably disinclination to bite the hand that fed them.  Possibly intelligence, which might go back to the not biting hand piece.

Maybe if you were a nobleman your daughter was impressed by a dragon you saw in a different castle - a little one, that would do tricks.  You borrow that dragon (you have your people borrow that dragon) for stud services because you want one for your daughter.  Of all the dragons sired by that one you keep two that seem promising.  Other nobles also try breeding dragons because it is cool and they are bored and need something to talk about with their noble friends.

4000 years later the dragons that remain are as similar to the original dragons as dogs are similar to wolves.  Unlike the goblins who still live in large societies of their own, the dragons have unavoidably been bred.  They are smaller, more docile and much smarter.  They are valued helpers and sometimes even advisors.  These humanized dragons are afraid of their wild kin in the wastelands and they are right to be afraid.  They do not have much in common.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually nice idea, maybe not most of them, but some dragons could be selectively breaded, but definitely for increased smart, you don't want doggo smarter then you,

Comment: This is a good point, although we don't really know what selective breeding of a *sapient* species will do. Human racial enslavement did not last thousands of years, and even so there was still interbreeding. OTOH, [Stockholm syndrome](Sotckholm Syndrome) is a thing, and since you'd probably breed for that, this seems plausible...

Comment: Oh, and Guy with jewels' names is correct; you'd probably want to breed them to be *less* intelligent. Specifically, you will breed them for *greater docility*, and I believe this tends to imply lesser intelligence. After a few thousand years of that, it's much less implausible that they can be useful as beasts of burden.

Comment: @Matthew - you can get intelligence, docility and sociability by breeding for neoteny: perpetual juvenile status.  That is how the Russian silver foxes turned out. That is how golden retrievers turned out.  Arguably that is one difference between humans and chimps.  Failure to grow up could also lead to smaller size.

Comment: Again, we don't have comparable examples with *sapient* species. My concern is how to have a fully sapient, intelligent species that doesn't resent being enslaved. OTOH, I could be wrong; [house elves](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/House-elf) are (mostly) a fictional example. You might still get *individuals* that don't like being enslaved, but they'd make interesting characters for your story.

Comment: @Willk I don't know a ton about silver foxes, so I'm curious -- are they more intelligent, or better at communicating with human? Measuring intelligence is hard. I think most people would call wolves smarter than dogs, but dogs are particularly good at reading people, which makes them better at, say, learning tricks (a poor but common informal measurement of intelligence).

Comment: @Zwuwdz - the domesticated fox story is an interesting one.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesticated_red_fox.

Answer (score 3):

Meat.

Taking their gold.

Their bodies could be restricted, only allowed to breathe fire, could be useful to get fires hotter so new metals can be smelted- that would be valuable tech to have.

They could be harvested for their scales like sheep- such a material could make valuable armor.

They could be in a dragon concentration camp, i.e. only enslaved because they are hard to kill, the task is logistically complex and will take years.

They could secrete a special substance that is beneficial to humans (e.g. if you've read Robin Hobb's Liveship Traders series)

Comment: Dragons are not hunted anymore, they are enslaved, long dead or hiding gods know where. And literally from all of creatures, dragon's meat is hardest to get. Same with gold, all of this dragon hunt thing were thousandth years ago, so all gold is long time took.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly they would be okay as a source of heat for smelting small quantities of metal, making glass etc. But thermodynamics suggests it's always going to be less efficient to feed fuel to a creature and then have that creature produce heat than it is to create the heat directly. Unless you have multiple dragons you'll never get 100% uptime on the dragonfire because they'll need time to eat and so forth. Overall it doesn't sound well suited to large industrial-scale operations.

Your best bet might be that dragonfire has magical properties and is required for certain alchemical processes, or for smelting small amounts of metal that requires to be infused with magic (magic rings, amulets, swords etc.) It's slavery on a small scale and only the wealthiest people can afford to have a dragonforge, because the feeding and security requirements are so tough to meet. Perhaps it's even required that the dragon be required to cooperate in the process, infusing the right magic into an item being created. This would set up an interesting tension: the dragons are intelligent and hate being enslaved, so what hold do the people have over them that is so strong that they co-operate despite the slavery? Does emergent knowledge of that hold then become a lever that could be used by other players in the story?

(Edit, to answer the questioner's query about what the hold might be since they've already been subjugated and chained).
Well, my proposed use for them was that they are an essential part of the process of making magic items *and have to co-operate in order for the magic item to work properly, by imbuing the correct magic*. So you perhaps need a stronger hold than mere chains to ensure that these intelligent, once-proud, extremely resentful creatures don't sabotage your magic ring. (A dragon might perhaps, instead of a true +6 ring of dodging, make a ring that appears to be a +6 ring of dodging but which only works when the wearer's pulse is below 110. Thus, in the heat of battle, it stops working and the bearer becomes much easier to kill.)
What that hold is, is up to you: it's a plot detail for you as the author to answer, not a world building question. But it's one that allows for some interesting possibilities.

If on the other hand you just want dragons as a means of turning meat into fuel, that still seems inefficient when you could just burn wood or coal (growing plant based fuel is much more resource efficient than growing plants to feed to animals to feed to a dragon which in turn will make heat). Yes you might be able to get a hotter flame, but how hot do you need? Ancient people were able to make furnaces well above a thousand degrees to make glass, fire pottery etc. and your world has a 17-18th century level of technology. Short of something a bit more special and unique such as my example above, I don't see why your people would bother keeping them as slaves at all. Except maybe as high status dangerous pets, a bit like Jabba the Hutt's Rancor Monster in Return of the Jedi.

Comment: What hold them? They've been beaten to the ground, and they would be again if risen. Why use dragons for heat source if normal fuels have greater efficiency? There are two reasons, one they can convert things like meat and other animal parts to heat easily, second they can achieve much higher temperature then achievable with normal fuel.

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge: what makes you so sure they're still enslaved?

4,000 years is a long time. Maybe there was a revolt, or even just a revolution. Meanwhile, this whole time they have been subjected (willingly or otherwise) to strict control of their nastier attitudes (certainly while they were enslaved this would have included eugenics / selective breeding programs), and over time have come to be less stuck-up to the point that they now work with your other people as friends and (with reasonable concession for physical differences) equals.

Of course, this could also still be a work in progress, providing a ready-made source of conflict. You could even have factions of dragons, from "throwbacks" that want to take over the world (or at least have their own nation) all the way to "grovelers" that think dragons are inferior and slavery should be reinstated.

Answer (score 0):

Scientists(or scholars/researchers) could study these dragons in order to create artifical objects/weapons/armor/machinery based on a dragon's anatomy and biological capabilities.

If the dragons are magic creatures they can be used as a magical source, to energize a city's walls or protections.

Honestly those are the only options I could think of that doesn't end with the dragon being dead in order to have it's corpse harvested for resources.

Answer (score -1):

They can be used as an elite transport system, for nobleman or an army. I mean, they are the winged type dragons right? A flying trasport would be very valuable in a 17-18 century society, instead of horses and carts. They also could be used as mercenaries themselves... The thing is how you make them obey their masters

Comment: The OP explicitly esxcluded these possibilities in the question...